# Is there a better way handle the logical conditions in this method?

Tags: java

I'm writing a class `Rectangle` which includes a method that returns +1/0/-1 based on whether a given point lies inside, on or outside the rectangle respectively.

I'm calculating the displacement of the point with respect to the 4 sides of the rectangle to do this. While the condition for "inside" is quite simple, that for "on the rectangle" has 8 conditions. Is there a better and more elegant way to handle the "on the rectangle" condition?

```
public class Rectangle {

private final Point bottomLeft;
private final Point topLeft;
private final Point topRight;
private final Point bottomRight;

//Other code here.


public int checkIfPointInside(Point point) {
    final int leftDisplacement = point.getX() - bottomLeft.getX();
    final int topDisplacement = point.getY() - topLeft.getY();
    final int rightDisplacement = point.getX() - topRight.getX();
    final int bottomDisplacement = point.getY() - bottomRight.getY();


    if (leftDisplacement > 0 && topDisplacement < 0 && rightDisplacement < 0 && bottomDisplacement > 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if ((leftDisplacement == 0 && topDisplacement < 0 && rightDisplacement < 0 && bottomDisplacement > 0)
        || (leftDisplacement == 0 && topDisplacement == 0 && rightDisplacement < 0 && bottomDisplacement > 0)
        || (leftDisplacement > 0 && topDisplacement == 0 && rightDisplacement < 0 && bottomDisplacement > 0)
        || (leftDisplacement > 0 && topDisplacement == 0 && rightDisplacement == 0 && bottomDisplacement > 0)
        || (leftDisplacement > 0 && topDisplacement < 0 && rightDisplacement == 0 && bottomDisplacement > 0)
        || (leftDisplacement > 0 && topDisplacement < 0 && rightDisplacement == 0 && bottomDisplacement == 0)
        || (leftDisplacement > 0 && topDisplacement < 0 && rightDisplacement < 0 && bottomDisplacement == 0)
        ||(leftDisplacement == 0 && topDisplacement < 0 && rightDisplacement == 0 && bottomDisplacement == 0)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
}
```

Note that the second condition is checking if the displacement is 0 only for one side or any two adjacent sides.

Comment: first step is to separate out each reusable condition to a function.

Comment: Isn't easier to just check the point X and Y against the top, left, right and bottom coordinate of the rectangle?

Comment: @MargaretBloom There isn't much difference between checking against the corners as opposed to the sides. It'll just modify the expression, not simplify the condition.

Comment: if its easier checking if its inside, and there are just another two options left, why not make it just (!inside && !outside) ?

Comment: @TejasChandrashekhar I haven't fully gone through your checks, but the simple check Margaret suggests only needs two tests with two comparisons each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are testing if *inside* and return 1. All good.

But then you test if *on rectangle* to return 0. Too complex.

Instead, test if *outside* and return -1.

```
if (leftDisplacement > 0 && rightDisplacement < 0 && bottomDisplacement > 0 && topDisplacement < 0) {
    return 1; // Inside
}
if (leftDisplacement < 0 || rightDisplacement > 0 || bottomDisplacement < 0 || topDisplacement > 0) {
    return -1; // Outside
}
return 0; // On Rectangle
```

Comment: Thanks! You're a genius! I spent so much on this problem but this approach never occurred to me. :-)

Comment: Think outside the box. *ROFL* 